# What is the idiom/proverb for "You have to fend for yourself, no one is going to come for our rescue"?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

What is the idiom/proverb for

> "You have to fend for yourself, no one is going to come for our rescue"?

Comment: *Every man for himself, and the Devil take the hindmost.*

Comment: [Sink or swim](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sink%20or%20swim#:~:text=%E2%80%94used%20to%20refer%20to%20a,job%2C%20it's%20sink%20or%20swim.)

Answer (score 3):

Adults are generally expected to ***stand on their own two feet***.

*If someone has to stand on their own two feet, they have to be independent and manage their lives without help from other people.
My father didn't mind whom I married, so long as I could stand on my own two feet and wasn't dependent on my husband.* (Collins Dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

you are **on (one's) own**   [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/On+Your+Own)

> By or through one's individual efforts or means.

As in:

> I found myself **on my own**, without the assistance or support of, or
>   dependence upon, anybody else.

Answer (score 1):

If you're Christian, or aiming your speech at Christians, you could consider **[God helps those who help themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_helps_those_who_help_themselves)**:

> The phrase "God helps those who help themselves" is a popular motto that emphasizes the importance of self-initiative and agency. The expression is still famous around the globe and used to inspire people for self help

<sup>Wikipedia</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You are ***all by yourself.***

TFD(idioms):

> **[by (one)self](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+myself)**
>
> **2**. Through one's own efforts alone. 
>   You can't move that table all by yourself! Here, let me help you.
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.

Answer (score 0):

The AHD of idioms definition for *every man for himself*, gives a meaning that is closest to yours:

> Each individual puts his or her own interests foremost. For example,
>
> - In this company no one helps anyone-it's every man for himself.
>
> In Chaucer's day this dictum was stated approvingly, meaning "***if you don't look out for yourself, no one else will***," but today such selfishness is usually censured. (quoted it by [FreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/it%27s+every+man+for+himself))

And I would have thought something along the lines would fit best:

> If you don't [verb], no one else will.

e.g.

> If you don't *save yourself/[run for your life](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run%20for%20one%27s%20life#:%7E:text=%3A%20to%20run%20to%20escape%20from%20great%20danger)*, no one else will.

(See [other variations](https://www.google.com/search?q=no%20one%20can%20help%20you%20if%20you%20don%27t%20help%20yourself&sxsrf=ALeKk03EfqZkEUCfZpU4qWOqOSL-8HQl1Q%3A1628416703582&ei=v6oPYYmVI6eG1fAPgpWVoAE&oq=no%20one%20can%20help%20you%20if%20you%20don%27t%20help%20yourself&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyBAgjECc6BwgjELADECc6BwgAEEcQsANKBAhBGABQhT1Y6kFgnVdoAXACeACAAW-IAbQCkgEDMS4ymAEAoAEByAEJwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjJ8Kb5lKHyAhUnQxUIHYJKBRQQ4dUDCA8&uact=5).)

Or else you could say:

> If you don't save/help/fight the fight yourself, then who will?